# Javascript to replace %0A for <br> html elements

Tags: javascript, newline, url-parameters

How can I display URL parameters to display on a new line on a HTML page using Javascript? I am working with this code below:

`return decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\%0A/g, "<br/>"));` 
but unable to display the results.

The above code is working because for example, if I `return decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\%20/g, " "));` I can see the results. Only when I use HTML elements it don't work i.e. `<br>`.

Here's a full code:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            if (pair[0] == variable) {
                return decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\%0A/g, "\n"));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**:

```
    getQueryVariable("line1");
    getQueryVariable("line2");
    getQueryVariable("line3");


$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#input1').val(getQueryVariable('line1')).trigger('keyup');
        });
        $('#input1').on('keyup', function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("pre#one").html(value);
        });
    });

<input type="hidden" id="input1" />
<ul id="texts">  
    <li><pre id="one"></pre></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Decode first, then replace the actual character (`\n`)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). (That said: I would certainly do what @AlexK. suggested. It's just not clear whether that would actually solve the problem. I'd do it regardless.)

Comment: You could always the `<pre></pre>` tag which will preserve white spaces including new lines.

Comment: @AlexK., thanks for your comment. I tried decoding it first as you suggested `return decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\%0A/g, "\n"));` but that didn't help :( unless I'm doing it wrong as I'm quite new to javascript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your comment :) I am trying to display the parameters from the URL using Javascript into a HTML page. The only thing that doesn't seem to work is a breaking long parameters into a new line. for example, in the `url` if i add `%0A` it doesn't break it down. I also tried what Alex suggested but it didn't worked for me :( PS: I have updated a full code that I'm currently working on as you requested bro. Thanks :)

Comment: @phuzi, thanks for your comment. I replaced my `li` with `pre` like you suggested but that didn't resolved it bro :(.

Comment: It works for me: https://jsbin.com/wezuwif/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @AlexK. thanks alot bro for the example. That worked for me too. I was implementing the script in header and by adding it to footer it worked for. Thanks again for your help.. really appreciate it :) have a great day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to take the query parameters and render them in a `ul`, with line breaks where line breaks appear in the query parameter (e.g., newline, character code 0x0A, aka `\n` in JavaScript and many similar languages).

That's a three-part process:

1. Decoding the parameter with `decodeURIComponent` (you're already doing that).
2. Escaping characters in the result which are special in HTML (in practice, just `&` and `<` is sufficient).
3. Replacing literal newlines, which are rendered as a space in HTML, with a line break **or** using a `pre` element or one of the `white-space` CSS properties that renders line breaks (such as `white-space: pre`).

Here's an example where we convert `\n` to `<br>`:

```js
// A stand-in for window.location.search, since
// we can't control that in snippets
var search = "?" + [
  "line1=" + encodeURIComponent("This is line1"),
  "line2=" + encodeURIComponent("This is line2 which has\nmore than one line"),
  "line3=" + encodeURIComponent("This is line3")
  ].join("&");

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
}

function escapeHTML(s) {
  return s.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
}

function addQueryParamLI(ul, param) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = escapeHTML(param).replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  return li;
}

var ul = document.getElementById("query-params");
addQueryParamLI(ul, getQueryVariable("line1"));
addQueryParamLI(ul, getQueryVariable("line2"));
addQueryParamLI(ul, getQueryVariable("line3"));
```

```html
Query parameters:
<ul id="query-params"></ul>
```

Here's an example using `white-space: pre` (only change is that we don't convert `\n` to `<br>` in `addQueryParamLI`, and we add the CSS property to the `li` elements with a rule):

```js
// A stand-in for window.location.search, since
// we can't control that in snippets
var search = "?" + [
  "line1=" + encodeURIComponent("This is line1"),
  "line2=" + encodeURIComponent("This is line2 which has\nmore than one line"),
  "line3=" + encodeURIComponent("This is line3")
  ].join("&");

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
}

function escapeHTML(s) {
  return s.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
}

function addQueryParamLI(ul, param) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = escapeHTML(param);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  return li;
}

var ul = document.getElementById("query-params");
addQueryParamLI(ul, getQueryVariable("line1"));
addQueryParamLI(ul, getQueryVariable("line2"));
addQueryParamLI(ul, getQueryVariable("line3"));
```

```css
#query-params li {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
Query parameters:
<ul id="query-params"></ul>
```

Comment: Wow @T.J.Crowder, thanks soooo much for a detailed explanation. It made a great sense and also the answer you provided worked for and a small tweak I had to do in my code, as using this script with `Textillate.js` so from the url parameters, it animates the information accordingly as this will be dynamic. Thank you once again bro and have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here, but I'm assuming you want to render the URI Encoded text in the page...

You could just insert the passed text in to a `<pre></pre>` tag after decoding so that white space is preserved.

```js
var string = "This%20text%20consists%20of%20several%0AURL%20encoded%20new-line%0Acharacters";

document.getElementById("content").innerText = decodeURIComponent(string);
```

```css
pre#content {
  font-family: Arial
}
```

```html
<pre id="content"></pre>
```

`<pre></pre>` will normally use a mono-spaced font but that can be overridden with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried what you suggested but it didn't display the parameter onto a new line by using `pre`. I have updated my code, for your inspection. I have got everything working except the new line =/